# Why is my Flask code erroring when I try to check if request.method == 'POST'?

Tags: html, post, flask, http-post

I am teaching myself Flask, and have a small working directory, including a page which allows the user to submit 'username' and 'password' fields. When the user clicks 'submit', I want to have my code call a function and pass in their input information.

However, I get an error when attempting to use "if request.method == 'POST':".
Can anyone tell me how to

A) Find the error message
B) Use the request.method properly?

Due to development reasons, I have to use Apache instead of hosting the Flask server locally, but that shouldn't be the cause.

microblog.py:

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort, make_response, render_template, flash, redirect
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='/sampledirectory/microblog/app/templates')

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if( request.method == 'POST' ):
    return "Test"
    form = LoginForm()
    return render_template('login.html', title='Sign In', form=form)
```

login.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Sign In</h1>
    <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <p>
            {{ form.username.label }}<br>
            {{ form.username(size=32) }}<br>
            {% for error in form.username.errors %}
            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{ form.password.label }}<br>
            {{ form.password(size=32) }}<br>
            {% for error in form.password.errors %}
            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </p>
        <p>{{ form.remember_me() }} {{ form.remember_me.label }}</p>
        <p>{{ form.submit() }}</p>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

If I remove the

```
if( request.method == 'POST' ):
    return "Test"
```

then the code displays the login.html page as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the form outside of the if statement and also indent the `return "test"`.

```py
from flask import Flask, request, abort, make_response, render_template, flash, redirect
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='/sampledirectory/microblog/app/templates')

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()

    if( request.method == 'POST' ):
        return "Test"

    return render_template('login.html', title='Sign In', form=form)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem was due to improper **code order**.

By default the page should return the login form but in your case you had created the form only when there was post request.

As you need the form to be appear in both GET and POST request, you can do like this.

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():

    form = LoginForm()

    if( request.method == 'POST' ):
        print('Got POST request')

    return render_template('login.html', title='Sign In', form=form)
```